# Operaciones Matriciales en Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.7

Tengo el siguiente programa en el cual hay una lista de lista y representa una matriz cuadrada. La función debe devolver True si la lista pasada como parámetro representa una matriz simétrica y False si no es simétrica, si es una matriz cuadrada. El problema de mi codigo es que funciona para ciertos casos y para otros no y no se como enmender mi error

```
import funcion

lista_lista = [
    [ 4,  54,  4,  2], 
    [ 7,  0,  25,  8], 
    [ 4,  10,  7,  0],
    [ 8,  82,  9,  9]
] 
muestra = funcion.estudio_matriz(lista_lista)
print(muestra)

def estudio_matriz(lista_lista):
    a = 0
    b = 0
    for elemento in numbers:
        if elemento[a] * elemento[b] == elemento[b] * elemento[a]:
            a += 1
            b += 1
            return Verdadero
    else: 
        return Falso
```

Comment: La funcion que adjuntas como ejemplo del intento realizado, no tiene ningún sentido. Dices que sólo te funciona en algunos casos, pero realmente no puede funcionar en ninguno. La función usa una variable `numbers` que en realidad no existe, retorna `Verdadero` o `Falso` que tampoco existen. Aún sin estos errores lo que hace tampoco tiene sentido pues multiplica elementos (a los que accede con un sólo índice, pese a que la matriz tiene dos dimensiones). Parece que hayas puesto código casi "al azar" para que pareciera que habías intentado algo. ¿Podrías explicar qué se supone que hace tu código?

Answer (score 1):

Puedes simplificar lo que haces usando `numpy`, como una matriz simetrica es una matriz que es igual que su transpuesta puedes usar el metodo `transpose` de `numpy`

```
import numpy as np

lista_lista = [
    [ 4,  54,  4,  2], 
    [ 7,  0,  25,  8], 
    [ 4,  10,  7,  0],
    [ 8,  82,  9,  9]
] 

matriz = np.array(lista_lista)
print(np.array_equal(matriz, matriz.T))
```

Salida

> False

`matriz.T` te retorna la transpuesta de un array de numpy y `np.array.equal` compara dos arrays, devolviendo `True` o `False`, creo que esta seria la manera mas sencilla de hacerlo

Answer (score 1):

**Problemas en tu código**

Hay varias cosas en tu código que no salen bien (Algunas ya las ha comentado @abulafia), así que iré paso a paso diciéndote lo que hace para que lo entiendas.

En primer lugar haces el bucle `for elemento in numbers`, sin haber declarado antes `numbers`, por lo que devolverá un error, así que deberías cambiarlo por `for elemento in lista_lista` o cambiar la función a `def estudio_matriz(numbers)`.

Cuando haces `if elemento[a] * elemento[b] == elemento[b] * elemento[a]` (antes has dado valor 0 a `a` y a `b`), lo que estás evaluando es `elemento[0] * elemento[0] == elemento[0] * elemento[0]` que como es obvio siempre va a ser cierto, por lo que siempre va a seguir leyendo lo que hay dentro del `if`.

Dentro del `if` pones un `return Verdadero` por lo que en cuanto se lea esa línea la función terminará devolviendo `Verdadero` y no volverá a hacer otra vuelta del bucle (en realidad devolverá un fallo que explico en el siguiente párrafo, pero una vez solucionado eso, esto es lo que ocurrirá).

Al poner `return Verdadero` devolverá un error ya que no se ha definido antes la variable `Verdadero`. Para que no ocurra habrá que poner `return 'Verdadero'` y nos devolverá esa cadena de texto, aunque no es lo habitual, lo normal es poner `return True` o `return False` y que nos devuelva un `Booleano`.